# Отсрочка событий внутри глобального таймера

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, теория

Пишу вполне простую игру.
И по опытности столкнулся с дилеммой.  Для реализации механики, нужно будет создавать массив с сотней координат, из этих координат, группируя по четыре точки, нужно будет составлять четырёхугольники. Но вопрос не в создании четырёхугольников, а с управлением данных.

Итак. С помощью «`touchesBegan`», «`touchesMoved`» и «`touchesEnded`» я создам массив с координатам,и и небольшим классом создам четырехугольники. Беда в том, что, когда я это всё сделаю, вся последовательность четырёхугольников будет создана сразу, как отработается запрос. Мне же, нужно контролировать скорость создания четырёхугольников и их удаление – скажем каждый следующий должен создаваться/удаляться секунду спустя (или любое другое время, которое я задам).

Всё обновление объектов на экране, у меня происходит с помощью `NSTimer`’а, который запускает класс «`doStep`», 60 раз в секунду; соответственно пауза ставится банальной остановкой «`doStep`». А вот как мне внутри глобального таймера, создавать «подтаймеры» (или аналоги), которые помогут мне создавать отсрочку для событий, я не понимаю – естественно эти «подтаймеры» должны будут останавливаться вместе по указке глобального.

Или вот пример очевидней. «`touchesBegan`» регистрирует касание. Сначала этого касания и до конца, переменная `int` должна с шагом в 10 раз в секунду (глобальный таймер обновляет всё 60 раз в секунду), увеличиваться на 1. И вот как это сделать, чтобы и глобальный таймер не страдал, и не пришлось генерировать сотню «подтаймеров» ради подобных исчислений переменной?

Наверняка должна быть теория или даже полноценная функция, которая поможет организовать подобные приёмы. Есть ли у вас опыт в подобном деле и можете ли вы им поделиться? *…пока я не умудрился прострелить и вторую ногу…*

Comment: а почему бы не сделать просто переменную, которая считает эти самые циклы. то есть, если у вас таймер выполняется 60 раз в секунду, а действие надо делать 10 раз в секунду, то этот дополнительный счетчик должен каждый из 60 циклов просто прибавлять 1, а когда будет 6, выполнять действие и обнуляться. таким образом действие будет выполняться каждый 6 циклов, что есть 10 раз в секунду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется удаление именно во время шага таймера (когда таймер делает обратный вызов), то лучше создать объект с очередью на удаление, который будет контролировать время на удаление и удалять объекты.
Если удаление во время шага таймера не критично, то используйте [dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2), [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/) (внутри можно сделать ожидание и отсрочено удалять объект, так же будет поддерживаться отмена), [peformSelector:AfterDelay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) (так же можно отменять, если не выполнился).
Ещё есть третий вариант, взять готовый framework для разработки игр ([Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/), [Unity](https://unity3d.com/ru)) и не пытаться реализовать собственный таймер.

Answer (score 1):

Заюзай простейший `dispatch_after`:

[dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after)

Передаешь туда блок, интервал времени, через который этот блок выполнить и очередь на которой все это должно случиться. В твоем случае это скорее 
всего будет `dispatch_get_main_queue()`